# Calculating month number by knowing difference between two days as number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have days as number which will give difference between two dates... For example : 01-03-2015 and 03-04-2015. I will get difference as 33 days. Now how to know this 33 days comes in which month... like 380 days comes in 13th month

Comment: 13th month, what's that? How are you showing that? Do you want 380 days from 1-03-2015 to be in the 13th month, or January 2016?

Comment: no no i shown an example i.e., 16-07-15 to 30-07-16 difference
 is 380 days so it will be in 13th month..like that...  i know the difference between two days as number so i want to know in which month that number will come..moreover i want month also as a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to get.  How about something that just rounds the difference divided by 30?

Say your `16-07-2015` is in A1, and `30-07-2016` is in A2. In B1, `=Round((A2-A1)/30,0)`

Comment: I have one more quest how to know start day and end day in a month..for example 13th month start day is 367 and end day is 395 like that

Comment: You're asking how to know the start date of the 13th month?  ...by 13th month, you mean the equivalent of a year and a month, no?

Comment: How's the start date of month 13 to be 367? There's 365 days in a year, so I'd think month 13 starts at day 366?

Comment: Yes its start with 366..@BruceWayne

Answer (score 0):

If you want `31-01-2015` and `01-02-2015` to evaluate to `1` month (althought it is only one day) you could use something like `=MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1)+12*(YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1))` where `A1` and `A2` are the two dates.

Otherwise something similar to Batma... I mean BruceWayne would work.